# New line for keyword inside pandas cell?

Tags: python, pandas, nlp

I want to make a new line within a pandas cell every time a keyword appears.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'text': ['I like python pandas', 
                                 'find all function input from help jupyter',
                                 'this has no bigrams',
                           'function input function input',
                            'function input']})
```

"I would like to have a new line inside each cell of text everytime, "input" occurs.  How would I do this?"

Comment: can you also add the keyword list and the expected df too

Comment: `df['text'] = df['text'].str.replace(input, "\n" + input)`? Might need to add `regex=False`.

Comment: @CJR I think "input" is the string to match/replace here (not a variable), so your code needs a slight modification: `df['text'] = df['text'].str.replace("input", "\ninput")`

Comment: @ongenz yes, thanks for pointing that out!